# Typical neuronal firing rates across the human cerebral cortex

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology

I would like to find a scientific article (or articles), which would summarize typical neuronal firing rates in different parts of the human cerebral cortex.

Any good references on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good reference to start you off where you can access an atlas of different properties of neurons. 
[Cell types from the Allen Brain Institute](http://celltypes.brain-map.org/)

Remember that when you say typical firing rates you have to specify *what kind* of cells you are talking about because interneurons can fire faster for example than pyramidal cells. Also there are differences in basal vs active firing rates.